# C++ WebView control in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8, winprt

Is there a web browser or web view control available to Windows Phone 8 applications written in C++? I've found a WebBrowser control but that seems to be only available in Windows Phone 7 written in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to directly use a WebBrowser control in C++. You'll have to create a [mixed C++ and XAML](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2012/11/05/what-s-new-in-windows-phone-8-5-out-of-8-quick-tip-creating-hybrid-applications.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20Devcorner%20%28DevCorner%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader) projects and overlay the  on top of your DirectX .

Note, using Hybrid XAML & D3D apps has a small performance hit over using pure C++ D3D apps. Even if you never show any XAML, just initializing the full CLR and loading up XAML for  is still pretty heavy. Read more about it on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714079%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714079%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

On other thing that might be applicable to you is that the [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) [has been ported over to WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207022%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) so it's accessible from C++. Alongside with the Launcher.LaunchUriAsync() method it allows you to navigate away from your app and open up IE10 to a specific page.